# About the properties of a type of inclusion structure

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I am interested in learning about the properties of a particular type of set that is relevant to my (non-mathematical) research. I apologize for my totally informal language below (I can read answers in set notation but it's a bad idea for me to try to write with it):

Elements of the set have inclusion relations, they can either overlap (they have an intersection that is less than either element); or one can include the other (they have an intersection that is equal to one element).

There are three clear axioms:

1. Almost every element of the set overlaps with at least one other element.
2. For every pair of overlapping elements, there is an element that exactly includes this pair (there is a "union element" for every such pair).
3. The exception to 1. is that there is a single element that is *only* a "union element" and that overlaps with no one (and, from 2., therefore is included by no one).

The best that I understand is that this is a specific type of partially-ordered set but that's a pretty general category. It seems very similar to a topological set but it requires unions rather than intersections. Is it familiar to anyone? Or is it nonsense?

If this is a familiar structure, I'd like to know if there are proofs for a few properties that I think must be true; primarily, that every element will have a unique upward and downward inclusion substructure, and that any subset of non-overlapping elements (excluding the Axiom 3 "top" element) will have a common upward including element.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) with a maximal element might be what you are looking for?

Comment: What is a union element?

Comment: I made up "union element", it is an element of the set that is effectively the union of two overlapping elements. So if you have AB and BC, the "union element" would be ABC.

Comment: There is a type of directed set, the "join semilattice" that at least includes the structure I described, but it does not require that each element has an intersection with another element. So I am looking for a specific brand of join semilattice.

Comment: Would you clarify whether the elements are subsets or not?

Comment: I am not sure, I think so since the relations are all inclusion relations - so I have in mind a kind of frame over which the elements are defined, and every element is a subset of this frame.

A different point is that, I believe that a structure satisfying those axioms everywhere will have one element (the 'axiom 3 element') that includes all the other elements. I'd like to know a proof of that is there is such a thing..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "almost every", do you mean "all but one" element p?
How can p be a union element if it does not include anything?

You could have a lattice with an order isolated point p or
a downward directed join semilattice and that isolated p.

A downward and upward directed porder and isolated p has
the required properties.  That shows if you want a join
semilattice, you will have to assume it.

Comment: My meaning is not that the Element P does not include anything; it does not *overlap* anything, but it (I think necessarily) includes *everything*. (When I say 'overlap' i mean an incomplete inclusion, an unordered intersection, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Is this a correct statement of your problem?

Let K be a collection of subsets of a set S;  K subset P(S).

A overlaps B when not empty A $\cap$ B proper subset A,B.

For all multipoint A in K, if A /= S,
. . then some B in K overlaps A.
For all overlaping A,B in K, A $\cup$ B in K.
S in K.

Comment: Yes that is a correct description!
If you can give me tips on how to study this structure and its properties, if it is something familiar that I can read about in the literature, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: For all multipoint A,B in K, A $\cup$ B in K.  That is all that I see is possible.  Perhaps you'd like assume the overlap in K.   What else would you want?  Notice the edits.